# Package pgfplots Error: "sorry, plot file could not be opened"

Tags: pgfplots, errors, gnuplot

I was met with this unpleasant surprise when trying to compile this file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[domain=-10:10,
        contour gnuplot={labels=false,levels={1}}
    ]{(x+1)^2/4-(y-2)^2/9};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The file produces this error:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{test_contourtmp0.table} could not be opened.
```

I did some digging and found out that my file is trying to borrow `gnuplot` functionality. Well, I installed `gnuplot` on my system, added `--shell-escape` and `--enable-write18` to my `pdflatex` configuration, but the error persisted.

I'm completely out of ideas. Please, help me.

Comment: This may not help much, but on my machine it compiles fine.

Comment: What setup are you using? I just upgraded mine to TeXlive 2018 (from TeXlive 2017), and TeXstudio is my compiler. Is there perhaps any explicit command I could use either in TeXstudio or in `gnuplot` that could fix my error?

Comment: I just type `pdflatex -shell-escape` on my updated TeXLive 2018 distribution. That is, on a console I type  `pdflatex -shell-escape  <file name>`. I never used TeXStudio, sorry.

Comment: Can't really help you with the error, but I have the same problem when I try to compile it. (Using TeXlive 2016)

Comment: Hmmm... What could it be?

Comment: most likely gnuplot not on path see my test at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456328/170109

Comment: @Sito if using windows then at cmd prompt enter> where /r c: gnuplot.exe (change c: to whatever drive it may be on) if mac/Linux use the equivalent search. In windows enter>path (and check if the resulting path before gnuplot from first reply is included in the path from second reply if not then that is the issue.